# Retrieving Facebook Live comment real time from my facebook live streaming

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to using Facebook Graph API and I am building a python script that retrieves the user's comments from my Facebook Live Stream real time. The Live stream is on my Facebook page and I am the admin of the page. I read that it is required to have page access token so i got one.

I registered an app which is linked to my Facebook page and got the Page Access token from the Graph API Explorer.

I tried to retrieve a past stream's comments on my page by using this.

`https://graph.facebook.com/{post_id}/comments?access_token={page_access_token}`

For Live stream it should be

`https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/{post_id}/live_comments?access_token={page_access_token}`

Only my comments had the "form" JSON object. Comments made by other users does not have the "form" JSON object.

**It looked like this**

`{"created_time":"2019-20-16T10:24:11+0000","message":"3","id":"442894059672528_442896329672301"}`

**Instead of**

`{"created_time":"2019-20-16T10:23:27+0000","from":{"name":"User A","id":"117461359653242"},"message":"1000","id":"442894059672528_442895933005674"}`

Is it something wrong with the permission or the page access token?

Edit 1: Does the app needs to be submitted and live on Facebook?

Comment: _“Does the app needs to be submitted and live on Facebook?”_ - yes, otherwise you won’t get any such data for users that don’t have a role in your app.

Comment: Do I need to request for new app/page access token after I submit the app to go live? Because I received  error requesting for access token with manage_page permission.

Comment: What error? If you set the app live, but do not have manage_pages approved in review yet, it will not work.

Comment: @04FS I just checked and realized that Individual Verification Status is not verified yet and the permission was not given. I will update again once its live with the approved permission. Is there any other way around this for the time being?

Comment: @04FS I am trying to submit the permission for review. However, my python script does not fall under any categories. Do you know how to bypass this? It gives me this message if I don't fill it up. "You do not have any platforms eligible for review. Please configure a platform on your Settings page."

Comment: You need to set up at least one platform. You’ll probably want to go with Website here, everything else makes probably less sense.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution tho above? as I am facing the same issue using the live_comments api when a user who does not have a role in our FB APP the json does not include user id and name.

When I see the docs it says live comments api require user_videos permission, did you try to get that approved from FB?

Comment: @HashaamAhmed I had to submit an app review request for the 'manage_pages' permission. Only once the app review request is approved by FB, then you can get the user's name as shown in my original post under the "Instead of" section. Hope it helps.

Comment: @thhVictor thanks for the response, I see and when I check about manage_pages permission it has been depreciated :( too bad but we have almost all the permission related to pages except for pages_manage_post, could that be the reason? Because I am in mid of applying for user_videos permission which I thought would be necessary for live comments api. Thanks.

Comment: @HashaamAhmed I see. It seems like manage_pages has been replaced by 4 new permissions. Check this link out and see if requesting for these permissions will help you in retrieving the user id and name. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version7.0/ I assumed you have tried out the four permissions in the link above.

It is also possible that  pages_manage_posts is required as well. You might want to request that too.

Comment: @thhVicto alright thanks for the link when I check the 4 new permissions I have 3 of them already approved except for pages_manage_ads which I doubt would be needed for user details. But Ill look into the pages_manage_posts. Currently in talk with FB direct support. Lets see what they have to say. Thank you.

Comment: If someone else has the issue like me for v9.0 fb apis, Fb approved the user_videos permissions and we started getting the user id and name for the users who dont have any role in FB APP. So we must need user_videos permission if need to use live comments api (streaming) @thhVictor thanks for the help :)

Comment: @HashaamAhmed good to hear that its working out for you. You're welcome!

Comment: @thhVictor Hi, and I am back to page 1 lol, now all of a sudden I dont get the FROM object from the live comment api :(

Comment: @HashaamAhmed have u check if any of ur permissions got revoked or something? check if you have received any notifications from FB

Comment: @thhVictor all seems to be fine from permissions side, last permission which got approved was user_videos and still its advanced access.

Comment: @thhVictor found the issue, was passing user access token to the api call. Changed to page access token and started working.

Comment: @HashaamAhmed sorry thought I had replied and good to hear that u got it working. Be mindful of using a valid page access token because invalid page access token will not throw any error. It will just give you comments without FROM fields.

Comment: @thhVictor nahh no worries :)) oh ok noted on that and thanks.